# Virt-Manager internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor

Tags: arch-linux, virtual-machine, qemu, virt-manager

Arch Linux

I created a qcow2 on the other drive using Virtual Manager.

I'm trying to use another drive for my VMs,
but when I try to create a new VM from an ISO, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 72, in cb_wrapper
    callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/createvm.py", line 2008, in _do_async_install
    installer.start_install(guest, meter=meter)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/install/installer.py", line 695, in start_install
    domain = self._create_guest(
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/install/installer.py", line 637, in _create_guest
    domain = self.conn.createXML(initial_xml or final_xml, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/libvirt.py", line 4408, in createXML
    raise libvirtError('virDomainCreateXML() failed')
libvirt.libvirtError: internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: 2022-05-22T20:39:03.671212Z qemu-system-x86_64: -blockdev {"node-name":"libvirt-2-format","read-only":false,"driver":"qcow2","file":"libvirt-2-storage","backing":null}: Could not open '/run/media/myuser/New Volume/VMS/kali.qcow2': Permission denied
```

I have tried the following:

- adding user=root and group=root to `/etc/libvirt/qemu.conf`, user=myuser group=kvm,
- made sure my user is part of the kvm and libvirt group,
- running `sudo virt-manager`,
- `chown qemu:qemu /run/media/myuser`
  and messing around with those permissions

but still no change.

Comment: try to move iso to /var/lib/libvirt/images